# If I withdraw my published paper from an SCI journal (Elsevier publisher) due to some conflicting issues; will it appear online after the withdrawal?

Tags: publications, journals, online-publication, withdraw

My paper is appeared online 6 months ago, but due to some confidentiality of the data used in that paper, the company asked us to withdraw the paper. Their opinion is that, the authors didn't ask the permission to use their data, they just cited them. 
Me and co-authors are OK with the withdrawal but we are confused that will it be there online after cancellation (with some notice in Red writing: CANCELLED due to this reason etc.) Or it will disappear online after cancellation?

Comment: This seems like a very good question to ask the publisher.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Exactly. Why you ask us and not directly the editor/publisher?

Comment: Reading material: https://www.elsevier.com/about/our-business/policies/article-withdrawal

Comment: @ Tobias, PsySp and Roland: Thanks a lot for these valuable answers.

Comment: There is no reliable way to make information on the internet go away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common practice is keeping your article online with a notice that it has been retracted. You can search for retracted articles to see examples for this situation or Retraction watch.